# How can i add key, value in PHP Object? (Codeigniter)

Tags: php, codeigniter

Example,

```
$params = array($demandnum,$demandnum,$demandnum,$demandnum,$demandnum,$demandnum,$demandnum,$demandnum,$demandnum,$demandnum,$demandnum,$demandnum );
$stmt = $this->db_gcm->query($query, $params);
$test = $stmt->row();

print_r($test);
```

Result,

```
stdClass Object( [server_price] => 32398.63 [server_unit] => 2 [network_price] => 0.00 
[network_unit] => 3 [storage_price] => 4948.02 [storage_unit] => 2 
[loadbalancer_price] => 2200.00 [loadbalancer_unit] => 1 
[additionalservice_price] => 105375.60 [additionalservice_unit] => 4 [support_price] => [support_unit] => 0)
```

I want to add key value in here.

Is there any good idea?

Answer (score 22, accepted):

> I want to add key value in here.

In where? `$test?` How about

```
$test->key = 'value';
```

Comment: its nice answer and working well..